# Tooltip (descpription) of Vaadin ComboBox items

Tags: combobox, tooltip, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to display tooltips when hovering the combobox items (unique tooltip for each row). There is .setDescription() method for components, even for Combobox, but it is for only the selected item.
How can I set tooltips for each combobox item?
I'm using Vaadin 7.3

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is a change of the tooltip after a row is selected what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I'm looking for tooltip which appears when you move the mouse on the options of the combobox. (before selectiing)

Comment: @Tibor Did you find a solution? If so, could you provide it as an answer?

Comment: No, I did not find, unfortunately. :(

Comment: for anyone still looking, there is a solution for Vaadin14 by now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61202914/vaadin14-tooltip-on-combobox-selection-mouseover/61203596#61203596