# Vaadin14 Tooltip on Combobox Selection Mouseover

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm using Vaadin 14 + Java.

I have a combobox with an enum as possible select items.

I want to display the enum in the combobox as possible selects, but I want to show the longer attribute "name" on mouseover / tooltip.

I saw that there has been the same question for older versions of Vaadin (and there was no solution apparently) and was wondering if there is an option to do that by now.

ComboBox

```
ComboBox<MyEnum> cb = new ComboBox<>();
cb.setLabel("MyComboBox");
cb.setItems(MyEnum.values());

//cb.setDescription --> does not exist for ComboBox?
```

My enum class:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    HIGH("High long name explanation"),
    MEDIOCRE("Mediocre long name explanation"),
    LOW("Low long name explanation");

    private final String name;

    private MyEnum(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue(){
      return name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the HTML level, creating a tooltip is done by defining a `title` property on the element.

But that title property must be placed on the options and not the comboBox itself, and the `ComboBox` doesn't have a java API for doing that like `comboBox.setItemTooltipProvider(..)`.

However, there is a java API for defining a Renderer, which will then be applied to each item. Instead of using a Renderer that simply returns the name of the option as String, we can also use a `ComponentRenderer` to be applied to each item. There you create a `Span` component containing the displayed item name (e.g. "HIGH"), and on that Span element you define the title property.

```
ComboBox<MyEnum> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
comboBox.setLabel("MyComboBox");
comboBox.setItems(MyEnum.values());
comboBox.setRenderer(new ComponentRenderer<>(item -> {
    Span span = new Span(item.name());
    span.getElement().setProperty("title", item.getValue());
    return span;
}));
```

[image]

Comment: so simple, yet so counterintuitive. Thanks!